# How to fix select count in group by Laravel 5.4 alway return empty

Tags: laravel, group-by

I select column and count with group by in Laravel but count value alway return empty.

```
$data = DB::table('my_table')
        ->select('column1', DB::raw('count(*) as data_count'))->where('column2', $column2_value)
        ->groupBy('column1')
        ->get();
```

Can anybody give me solution to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running the raw query to make sure it will definitely return results?

Comment: I've been tried. But it return empty.

Comment: So there aren't any rows in the database where `column2` =`$column2_value`?!?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried running your code. And it's working fine.
Below is the output which I am getting.

```
*** query ***
    DB::table('table_name')
             ->select('name', DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
             ->where('role','user')
             ->groupBy('name')->get();

*** output ***
    array:7 [▼
      0 => {#117 ▼
        +"name": ""
        +"count": 5
      }
      1 => {#119 ▼
        +"name": "test comp 2 owner"
        +"count": 1
      }
      2 => {#120 ▼
        +"name": "Test Expert User"
        +"count": 1
      }
      3 => {#121 ▼
        +"name": "Test namwe"
        +"count": 1
      }
      4 => {#122 ▼
        +"name": "test owner"
        +"count": 1
      }
      5 => {#123 ▼
        +"name": "Test Prof User"
        +"count": 1
      }
      6 => {#124 ▼
        +"name": "Test Wp Prof User"
        +"count": 1
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I don't understand why running on my version is faulty. I use Laravel 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = DB::table('my_table')
    ->selectRaw('column1, count(column1) as data_count'))->where('column2', $column2_value)
    ->groupBy('column1')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I've been tried. It return exception: 
ErrorException in Builder.php line 907: array_merge_recursive(): Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: Delete 'bootstrap/cache/services.json' and re-run ' cache:clear' 'composer update' and this should solve it.

Comment: Yes. After clear it was running. But data_count alway return empty.